# lxd container: port forwarding like docker

Tags: port-forwarding, lxc, containers, lxd

Is there a way to do port-forwarding in lxd-containers like docker does?

I heard some rumours that there is no easy way.

According to the homepage of lxd this is their goal:

> Intuitive (simple, clear API and crisp command line experience)

For me port forwarding is an important part.

I am not in a hurry. If it is planed for a future release, this would be a valid answer.

Comment: There's no easy way only if `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <IP> -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT --to <IP>:<port>` is hard. Incidentally, if you're going to work from rumours, you probably want to ask the source of the rumours, not other people.

Comment: @womble if this one line is all which is needed, then I will upvote an accept your answer. Please fill in your comment as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but it's possible to just assign a network interface to your container. So, there isn't so much need to do port forwarding any more...

Comment: @gf_yesterday you said "it's possible to assign a network interface to your container". I can handle this solution (assigning a new network interface) ... but I am lazy. I prefer port forwarding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the developers wrote in [this issue](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/591) about the topic:

> This has been closed, but to give a clear answer: lxd (at least as
> currently intended) will not do host networking.  So in general
> you would port-forward to a web-server in a lxd container the same
> way you would do with lxc - you can pass in a nic from the host
> into the container and have your local router provide it its own
> address;  or use route-based networking to container veths;  or
> use iptables forwarding to forward host traffic into the container
> (which is what I usually do).

> See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-network
> for more information.

<s>So, I'm afraid, as things stand currently, there is no port forwarding, neither now nor in the future.</s> (This prediction [turned out to be not true](https://serverfault.com/a/1006638/171476))

Comment: I up-voted your answer. But one question remains: You know the current state. Great. But do you know the future?

Comment: @guettli: Thanks, glad that it helped. Nobody knows what the future will look like, but, as I wrote in my answer, I wouldn't be too optimistic: One of the devs clearly stated that they've got no plans to introduce host networking, so I doubt (as it currently stands) that port forwarding will be possible.

Answer (score 6):

Four years later, the prediction given in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/742951/171476) was fortunately too pesimisitc. Port forwarding has been implementented in LXD in the meantime as is [documented here](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/instances#type-proxy).

To forward port 80 on the host to 8080 in the container, simply do

```
lxc config device add jitsi port1 proxy listen=tcp:<hostip>:80 connect=tcp:<ontainerip>:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the update!